# python cookiejar: CookieJar instance has no attribute 'load'

Tags: python, python-2.7, cookies, urllib2

I am quite new to python and I am trying to set a cookie using the `cookielib` library of python, like so:

```
>>> import cookielib
>>> cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
>>> cj.load('cookies.txt')
```

and I get thrown this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: CookieJar instance has no attribute 'load'
```

I think the same code used to work earlier, but I am entirely unsure why this is happening now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`load()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/cookielib.html#cookielib.FileCookieJar.load) is a method on the *[`FileCookieJar()` class](https://docs.python.org/2/library/cookielib.html#cookielib.FileCookieJar)* only, a subclass of [`CookieJar()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/cookielib.html#cookielib.CookieJar).

Looks like you got confused between the two somewhere.

The following works:

```
import cookielib
cj = cookielib.FileCookieJar()
cj.load('cookies.txt')
```

Comment: Thanks a tonne @Martijn: I now use `cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()` and that works aswell (since my cookie is in lwp format). Accepted your answer!

Comment: @JohnJ: yes, `LWPCookieJar` is a further subclass of `FileCookieJar` specifically for that file format.